# Sum of a Sum of a Squared Difference

Tags: maximum-likelihood

[image: Im Lost]
How did the author jump from the second equation to the third equation? I suspect there’s a rule I’m forgetting that allows for this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm more interested in how they jumped from the first line to the second. Where do the 8s and 7s come from, what happened to good old $\mu$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that

\begin{align}
-\left(\sum_{i=1}^{160} (x_i - 8)^2 - \sum_{i=1}^{160} (x_i - 7)^2\right) & = 
-\left(\sum_{i=1}^{160} (x_i^2 - 16x_i + 64) - (x_i^2 - 14x_i + 49)\right) \\
& = -\left(\sum_{i=1}^{160} (-2x_i + 15)\right) \\
& = 2\sum_{i=1}^{160} x_i - 2400 \tag{1}\label{eq1}
\end{align}

As you can see, the $15$ is a constant repeating $160$ times for a total of $15 \times 160 = 2400$. Also, the author used the minus sign in front to remove the first minus sign for the $2x_i$, moved the $2$ outside the summation and changed the plus to a minus for the sum of $2400$.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for breaking that down for me.

Comment: @Seraphim You're welcome. I'm glad I could be of some help.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler way,
using 
$a^2-b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)
$,
is

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{i=1}^{160} (x_i - 8)^2 - \sum_{i=1}^{160} (x_i - 7)^2)
&=\sum_{i=1}^{160} ((x_i - 8)^2 -(x_i - 7)^2)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{160} ((x_i - 8) -(x_i - 7))((x_i - 8) +(x_i - 7))\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{160} (-1)(2x_i -15)\\
&=160\cdot 15-2\sum_{i=1}^{160} x_i\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Simpler? Debatable. Cooler? Yes.

Comment: I think it's simple because you don't have to expand the squares.